# IBM Bluemix login through command line interface using 'cf' command

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

While i am trying to login to IBM Bluemix through command line interface using cf l -a https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net (UK region) i am getting below error.

'cf' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you downloaded/installed cf? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#downloads

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error, it seems that you don't have the [Cloud Foundry command line interface (cli)](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/) installed or it cannot be found in your environment. The CF cli is available for several platforms and the link provides detailed descriptions for setting it up including for Windows (is this your platform?).

After the cli commands like `cf` are installed, you can use them to login to Bluemix and deploy or manage applications and services.